# How to Match the string and remove a specified strings belongs to it using Perl

Tags: perl

I want to match "current_line abc/123" and remove ins_bug below it by just keeping "size  "  string belongs it. If Current_line is not abc/123, I want to print everything.

Input

```
  current_line
  current_line  abc/123/187/
  ins_bug       {[sgd/hsjfk/123]}
  size          hkjd/hkjdjl/hjkj


 current_line
 current_line  dsfd
 ins_bug       {[hds/hdf/123]}
 size          kjfgkf/hkdjf

 current_line
 current_line  ahd/ijk/
 ins_bug       {[sgd/hsjfk/123]}

 current_line
 current_line  abc/123/jhk/
 ins_bug      {[hk/hsjfk/123]}
 ins_bug      {[hkcd/1235/465]}
 size         jfkdjgfdl/hkshfhd
 ins_bug      {[hdkc/563/545]}
 size          kjfhgkfjglf/hskahfjd

 current_line
 current_line  hjkd
 ins_bug       {[hds/hdf/123]}
 size          djfkljlg/hkdsgj
 ins_bug       [dsf/dfdg/dfdfd]
 size          dklgfks/jdskljfldlk

 current_line
 current_line  abc/123/897
 ins_bug       dgds/hsgds/412
 size         jkjfd/kjdjf
```

OUTPUT

```
current_line
current_line  abc/123/187/

size    hkjd/hkjdjl/hjkj


 current_line
 current_line  dsfd
 ins_bug      {[hds/hdf/123]}
 size          kjfgkf/hkdjf

 current_line
 current_line  ahd/ijk/
 ins_bug      {[hkj/hsjfk/123]}

 current_line
 current_line  abc/123/jhk/
 size          jfkdjgfdl/hkshfhd
 size          kjfhgkfjglf/hskahfjd

 current_line
 current_line  hjkd
 ins_bug       {[hds/hdf/123]}
 size          djfkljlg/hkdsgj
 ins_bug       [dsf/dfdg/dfdfd]
 size          dklgfks/jdskljfldlk

 current_line
 current_line  abc/123/jkjjkj
 size          jkjfd/kjdjf
```

I tried to write this code

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open (fh, "sas.txt" );
open (OUT, " > out.txt");

$x = 0;
my $mat = qr/abc\/123/;

while ($line = <fh>)
{
    chomp ($line);
    if ($line =~ m/current_line/)
    {
         print OUT "$line \n";
         $x = 1;
    }
    elsif ($x == 1)
    {
         if ($line =~ m/$mat/)
         {
              print OUT " $line \n" unless $line =~ m/ins_bug/; 
         }
    }
    else
    {
          print OUT " $line \n ";
    }
}
close (fh);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat sas.txt | perl -pe 'BEGIN {$abc=0} m#(current_line)\s+(abc/123)?#; if ($1) { $abc=$2 ? 1 : 0 } if ($abc && m#ins_bug#) {$_=""}' > out.txt
```

Keep track if we are in the "abc/123" section.

```
BEGIN {$abc=0}
```

Match the current_line section, optionally matching abc/123.

```
m#(current_line)\s+(abc/123)?#;
```

If we've matched abc/123, mark it, otherwise unmark it.

```
if ($1) { $abc=$2 ? 1 : 0 }
```

When in the abc/123 section, if we come across an "ins_bug" line, skip it.

```
if ($abc && m#ins_bug#) {$_=""}
```

Comment: that's amazing explanation. I tried it and it worked for me. and its a great learning for me

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) range operator you can remove a large chunk of code. Here's how you can use it within the framework of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# use lexical file handles
open my $fh_in, '<', 'sas.txt'
    or die "Could not open input file";
open my $fh_out, '>', 'out.txt'
    or die "Could not open output file";

while(<$fh_in>) {
    # use the .. range operator (see perldoc op) to only
    # match lines between and including the two patterns
    if (m!current_line\s+abc/123!..m!^\s*$!) {
        next if /ins_bug/;
    }

    print $fh_out $_;
}
```

Comment: IMO a range operator like this is better than setting a flag.